# Magento libraries working with jQuery issue?

Tags: magento

Hi I am working with magento at the moment and want to integrate a jquery slideshow with rounded corners using jquery. However I am having a problem using jquery with the others, even though I have wrapped my code in:

```
(function($) {        
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

You can find a link to my js file [here](http://www.getbranded.co/magento/js/jquery.corner.js).

I am calling jquery-latest from the jquery site/cdn, and the theme is default.

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have correctly wrapped your code in an anonymous function does your theme also call jQuery's [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for Prototype's sake?

Comment: That worked great thanks clockworkgeek, I did some research before coming here and did see that but also saw if u wrap it in jquery only tags it would be ok but anyway your way worked so im happy :)

Comment: That's great. Congratulations.